# What is the function of the XBee / USB switch on an XBee shield?

Tags: serial, xbee, usb

I recently bought an XBee shield ([this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-For-Arduino-ZigBee-XBee-Bluetooth-Bee-V03-Shield-Module-Wireless-Control-Hot/301457628487?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D30543%26meid%3D6648f5c1a8f54e9e92e799f4092616ce%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D221568487830&rt=nc)). The shield has a switch that seems to switch between USB/XBee. However, there is no USB port. What exactly is the switch supposed to do?

Comment: it looks like the switch connects / disconnects the XBee to the hardware serial port. And must be disconnected to program the board.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone does ask the same question in the future, this is the explanation for the USB/XBee switch functionality on the XBee Pro Shield V3 [image: XBee Pro Shield V3]

The switch serves to connect/disconnect the XBee Pro shield v3 to the Hardware TX->1 & RX<-0 Lines of the Arduino. Moving the switch to the USB side, allows you to disconnect the XBee Pro shield v3 from the hardware serial lines and upload code to your Arduino. If the switch is on the XBee side, this allows your XBee Pro shield v3 to use the TX->1 and RX<-0 lines of the Arduino and if you want to upload code to your Arduino, you would have to remove the shield otherwise it would result in an error trying to upload code. [image: Arduino Uploading Error]

Answer (score 1):

Better to check connection with tester. I think it switches connection to bluetooth module directly to your PC (with usb serial converter which is on arduino board)  or with arduino microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that the switch has the same functionality as the "serial select" switch on the official Arduino Wireless Shield for XBee modules. Therefore the explanations on the switch settings given there (http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoWirelessShield) probably apply also to your board.

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore... "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

The Xbee shield has aswitch labled Xbee/USB. This determines how the Xbee's serial communication connects to the serial communication between the microcontroller (ATmega8 or ATmega168 or Atmega328) and FTDI USB-toserial chip on the Arduino board.

In the Xbee position the Xbee module is connected to the RX pin of the microcontroller; and DIN is connected to TX. Note that the RX and TX pins of the microcontroller are still connected to the TX and RX pins (respectively) of the FTDI
chip - data sent from the microcontroller will be transmitted to the computer via USB as well as being sent wirelessly by the Xbee module. The microcontroller, however, will only be able to receive data from the Xbee module, not over USB from the computer.

In the USB position, the DOUT pin the Xbee module is connected to the RX pin of the FTDI chip, and DIN on the Xbee module is connected to the TX pin of the FTDI chip. This means that the Xbee module can communicate directly with the computer -
however, **IMPORTANT** this only works if the microcontroller has been removed from the Arduino board. If the microcontroller is left in the Arduino board, it will be able to talk to the computer normally via USB, but neither the computer nor the microcontroller will be able to talk to the Xbee module.

THANKS TO RS-COMPONENTS FOR THE DETAILS!!!!!